# expression must be modifiable lvalue in iar

Tags: msp430, iar

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>
void main(void)
{
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;

  if(CALBC1_1MHZ = 0xFF || CALDCO_1MHZ) //error line
  {
    while(1);
  }
  BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_1MHZ;
  DCOCTL = CALDCO_1MHZ;

  P1DIR = 0x40;
  P1OUT = 0;

  while(1)
  {
    P1OUT = 0x40;
    _delay_cycles(50000);
      P1OUT = 0;
    _delay_cycles(50000);
  }
}
```

I am writing this code and i am getting the error

> expression must be modifiable lvalue in the if statement.

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Stop dumping your code unformatted. You're wasting our time unless you actually make some effort to format the code for easy review.

Comment: I really can't make heads or tails out of that. Some code must be lost, as "include void main(void)" can't possibly be correct.

Comment: thanks dave for correcting it. i want to see the output in oscilloscope i.e. square wave. I am not able to see. help me with this.

Comment: It appears that your first "if" statement will always be true, so you will always be stuck in that first "while(1)" loop.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to use `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Thank you. I used ==, the error is gone but showing the warning that _delay_cycles declared implicitly.

Comment: Yes, it does look like _delay_cycles is declared implicitly, as I don't see am explicit declaration anywhere (I'm sure that it's not in msp430g2553.h, and that's your only include file). You need to declare it in whatever .h file is responsible.

Comment: Also, you should look at the Barr Group's book "Embedded C Coding Standard". The bug that you had would have been prevented had you been using that standard.

Comment: #include <intrinsics.h> to correct _delay_cycles warning